# Is there a Sinch example using an inbox?

Tags: sinch

Sinch seems to serve the purpose find for sending messages but is there an example, perhaps using Parse, where missed messages accumulate in an inbox and allow for responding to the missed message and keeping the thread of messages?

Answer (score 0):

The messages will be delivered to the client as soon as you launch the app, then you can save it to parse if you like.